# iphone suddenly not detected on ubuntu 22.04

Tags: networking, iphone, ios

I am currently trying to connect an Iphone 12 IOS 16 to my machine and while it used to work before without needing anything other than connecting, after buying the new phone, it started acting up.

I've reinstalled all the libraries necessary and disconnected the device more times than I can count. It was detected 2 or 3 times out of a 100, and it once gave me an error which said something along the lines of "error mux (-8)". I use it to access a windows 10 virtual machine and direct the iphone usb to there, but it hasn't been working now.

This is what it shows in the usbmuxd status

```
      sudo systemctl status usbmuxd ● usbmuxd.service - Socket daemon for the usbmux protocol used by Apple devices
      Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/usbmuxd.service; static)
      Active: active (running) since Sun 2023-07-30 18:31:00 EEST; 3s ago
        Docs: man:usbmuxd(8)    Main PID: 21840 (usbmuxd)
       Tasks: 2 (limit: 38257)
      Memory: 1.9M
         CPU: 270ms
      CGroup: /system.slice/usbmuxd.service
          └─21840 /usr/sbin/usbmuxd --user usbmux --systemd
```

I've tried to stop it and start it again

```
sudo systemctl stop usbmuxd 
sudo usbmuxd -f -p
[3] usbmuxd v1.1.1 starting up [18:31:34.743][3] Using
libusb 1.0.25 [18:31:34.747][3] Initialization complete
[3] Connecting to new device on location 0x1000f as ID 1
[1] RX transfer stalled for device 1-15
[3] Removed device 1 on location 0x1000f
```

Also tried *sudo idevicepair unpair && idevicepair pair* but it simply shows "no device detected"

Edit: I use a type-C converter as my PC only has USB and my charger is type-C, and it has always worked, but I thought maybe to change the cable and when I did it detected my iphone, but 2 minutes later and after trying to direct it into the VM, which it still didn't detect, it stopped detecting it and completely stopped charging the iphone (still works normally tho). I don't have any other cable and I am sure my normal cable used to work and everything was smooth before.

The only new thing I did was having a new iphone, and doing "*sudo ideviceinfo*" shows no device detected. What am I supposed to do? What are the fixes because I've spent the last 6 hours searching with nothing to fix it apparently

Update: this is what showed up when I *sudo journalctl  --follow*

```
 Jul 30 22:11:05 kernel: usb 1-10: new high-speed USB device number 42 using xhci_hcd 
 Jul 30 22:11:05 kernel: usb 1-10: New USB device found, idVendor=05ac, idProduct=12a8, bcdDevice=13.04 
 Jul 30 22:11:05 kernel: usb 1-10: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=3 
 Jul 30 22:11:05 kernel: usb 1-10: Product: iPhone 
 Jul 30 22:11:05 kernel: usb 1-10: Manufacturer: Apple Inc. 
 Jul 30 22:11:05 kernel: usb 1-10: SerialNumber: 00008101000224D13C22001E 
 Jul 30 22:11:05 mtp-probe[32880]: checking bus 1, device 42: "/sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:01.3/0000:03:00.0/usb1/1-10" 
 Jul 30 22:11:05 mtp-probe[32880]: bus: 1, device: 42 was not an MTP device
 Jul 30 22:11:05 mtp-probe[32887]: checking bus 1, device 42: "/sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:01.3/0000:03:00.0/usb1/1-10" 
 Jul 30 22:11:05 mtp-probe[32887]: bus: 1, device: 42 was not an MTP device

  Jul 30 22:11:07 kernel: [UFW BLOCK] IN=enp34s0 OUT= MAC=2c:f0:5d:0b:ec:fc:34:e6:ad:9f 91:ec:08:00 SRC=192.168.1.183 DST=192.168.1.12 LEN=1254 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=128 ID=27273 PROTO=UDP SPT=3702 DPT=35053 LEN=1234 

  Jul 30 22:11:07 kernel: [UFW BLOCK] IN=enp34s0 OUT= MAC=2c:f0:5d:0b:ec:fc:34:e6:ad:9f:91:ec:08:00 SRC=192.168.1.183 DST=192.168.1.12 LEN=1254 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=128 ID=27274 PROTO=UDP SPT=3702 DPT=35053 LEN=1234 

  Jul 30 22:11:07 kernel: [UFW BLOCK] IN=enp34s0 OUT= MAC=2c:f0:5d:0b:ec:fc:34:e6:ad:9f:91:ec:08:00 SRC=192.168.1.183 DST=192.168.1.12 LEN=1254 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=128 ID=27275 PROTO=UDP SPT=3702 DPT=35053 LEN=1234 

  Jul 30 22:11:07 kernel: [UFW BLOCK] IN=enp34s0 OUT= MAC=2c:f0:5d:0b:ec:fc:34:e6:ad:9f:91:ec:08:00 SRC=192.168.1.183 DST=192.168.1.12 LEN=1254 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=128 ID=27276 PROTO=UDP SPT=3702 DPT=35053 LEN=1234 

  Jul 30 22:11:08 kernel: [UFW BLOCK] IN=enp34s0 OUT= MAC=2c:f0:5d:0b:ec:fc:34:e6:ad:9f:91:ec:86:dd SRC=fe80:0000:0000:0000:5b19:4b3c:aeb1:bb97 DST=fe80:0000:0000:0000:fc4a:c3d0:50a6:d5ee LEN=1288 TC=0 HOPLIMIT=64 FLOWLBL=921699 PROTO=UDP SPT=3702 DPT=47102 LEN=1248 

  Jul 30 22:11:08 kernel: [UFW BLOCK] IN=enp34s0 OUT= MAC=2c:f0:5d:0b:ec:fc:34:e6:ad:9f:91:ec:86:dd SRC=fe80:0000:0000:0000:5b19:4b3c:aeb1:bb97 DST=fe80:0000:0000:0000:fc4a:c3d0:50a6:d5ee LEN=1288 TC=0 HOPLIMIT=64 FLOWLBL=921699 PROTO=UDP SPT=3702 DPT=47102 LEN=1248 

  Jul 30 22:11:08 kernel: [UFW BLOCK] IN=enp34s0 OUT= MAC=2c:f0:5d:0b:ec:fc:34:e6:ad:9f:91:ec:86:dd SRC=fe80:0000:0000:0000:5b19:4b3c:aeb1:bb97 DST=fe80:0000:0000:0000:fc4a:c3d0:50a6:d5ee LEN=1288 TC=0 HOPLIMIT=64 FLOWLBL=921699 PROTO=UDP SPT=3702 DPT=47102 LEN=1248 

  Jul 30 22:11:08 kernel: [UFW BLOCK] IN=enp34s0 OUT= MAC=2c:f0:5d:0b:ec:fc:34:e6:ad:9f:91:ec:86:dd SRC=fe80:0000:0000:0000:5b19:4b3c:aeb1:bb97 DST=fe80:0000:0000:0000:fc4a:c3d0:50a6:d5ee LEN=1288 TC=0 HOPLIMIT=64 FLOWLBL=921699 PROTO=UDP SPT=3702 DPT=47102 LEN=1248 

  Jul 30 22:11:18 kernel: [UFW BLOCK] IN=enp34s0 OUT= MAC=01:00:5e:00:00:01:ec:3e:b3:3a:74:90:08:00 SRC=192.168.1.1 DST=224.0.0.1 LEN=36 TOS=0x00 PREC=0xC0 TTL=1 ID=24053 PROTO=2
```

Comment: Watch `sudo journalctl  --follow` as you connect the device

Comment: @waltinator Added what was shown in the post.

Comment: Please read https://askubuntu.com/help/formatting . Take the [tour]. Please change the block quotes to code format.